# Dúvida ferramenta eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, getters-setters

É possível gerar *Getters* and *Setters* de forma automática apenas de variáveis selecionadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Menu "source -> generate getters and setters"  e aí vc escolhe quais quer gerar. Agora para gerar a partir do que já está selecionado, não sei...

Answer (score 2):

Clicando com o botão direito na classe você consegue definir os métodos getters/setters:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E uma vez na tela apresentada, você poderá selecionar os atributos, bem como se somente gerar getter ou setter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi escapistabr, obrigado pela resposta,  esse é o jeito padrão que utilizo para gerar os getters and setters, porém, estou mexendo numa classe com muitas variáveis, e gostaria de gerar os getters e setters apenas das variáveis que eu selecionar, deixá-las marcadas para poder gerar **apenas** das marcadas. Dessa maneira vem com todas as variáveis que existem na classe...